# Contradiction with Maxwell's demon thought experiment

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy, information

There is an important inequality in thermodynamics which states that TdS>=dQ, where T is the temperature of the system in question (or, more generally, the temperature of the surroundings), dS is the (infinitesimal) change in entropy of the system, and dQ is the (infinitesimal) net amount of heat supplied to the system. The symbol >= means greater than or equal to. This is really just one form of the second law of thermodynamics. But it seems like with Maxwell's demon, you can decrease the entropy of a gas (our "system" in this case) without interacting with the particles of the gas (you simply open or close a door), in which case no heat can be supplied to or taken out of the gas, meaning that dQ=0. But yet, the entropy of the gas decreases (which is easy to see if, say, we picture the version of the experiment where the demon accumulates all the particles into one half of a box), which means that the inequality above is violated for the gas. What's going on here? Although the entropy of the whole universe (system + demon) doesn't decrease (because the demon acquires information about the states of the gas molecules, increasing its own entropy, whose entropy increase is then greater than or equal to the entropy decrease in the gas), there is still this contradiction with that inequality above, it seems.

Comment: There are many wonderful questions already on this site about Maxwell's demon. Check the 'Related' section on the right-side of this page. I'm sure you can find your answer there.

Comment: @ArturodonJuan No, I didn't find anything like this there. That's why I decided to ask.

Comment: In the inequality $TdS \ge \delta Q$ the temperature $T$ is neither the temperature of the "system" nor of its "surroundings". Instead $T$ is the temperature of the *interface* at which  $\delta Q$ is transferred from the "surroundings" to the "system" and then $dS$ is the increase of entropy of the "system".

Comment: What instrument you have in mind that can open/close the door without interacting with the particles themselves? How would the demon or the instrument know *when* to close/open without interaction?

Comment: @hyportnex Well, I've been told that the demon can interact with the particles (and door for that matter) by an arbitrarily small amount. That's why the solution to Maxwell's demon isn't, say, solved by saying that there is an entropy increase associated with the interaction with the door or the measurement of the properties of the gas molecules. Instead, you need to invoke information theory. So again, I don't see how the paradox I describe in my question can be solved. Also, I guess my question works the same no matter how you define T, doesn't it?

Comment: That is the point of Maxwell's Daemon, to show that, in a superficial analysis, it  violates the second law

Comment: The inequality holds when heat flows from hot to cold. In the case of Maxwels's demon heat flows from cold to hot.

Comment: @Wolphramjonny But isn't it also the point that information theory is supposed to resolve the second law? In which case, there should be a solution to the problem I address?

Comment: @stuffu But then what's the point of the second law, if the very inequality that defines it doesn't hold when heat flows from cold to hot, the very thing that's supposed to be impossible without interaction with the environment (through heat exchange)?